# SQL to return rows which have duplicate values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return the rows showing `OrderId`s which have duplicate values in the `Notes` column, ie different `OrderId`s which have the same value in the `Notes` column.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
    [OrderId],
    [Notes]
FROM
    [ord].[LineItems]
GROUP BY 
    OrderId, Notes
HAVING 
    COUNT(Notes) > 1;
```

The problem with the above query is that it is returning false-positives, ie rows which have duplicates in the `Notes` column, but they have the same `OrderId` (there can sometimes be duplicate rows showing the same OrderIds and Notes values, because there are different values in other fields).

I only want it to return *unique* `OrderId`s which have the duplicated values in the `Notes` column. How can I remove these false-positives?

Sorry this has been hard to explain, and the database I'm working with isn't well normalized.

Answer (score 3):

You should be aggregating by `Notes` and then checking the distinct count of orders:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Notes
    FROM LineItems
    GROUP BY Notes
    HAVING MAX(OrderId) <> MIN(OrderId)
)

SELECT *
FROM LineItems li
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte t WHERE t.Notes = li.Notes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need `EXISTS` to get all the duplicate `Notes`:

```
SELECT o.[OrderId], o.[Notes]
FROM [ord].[LineItems] o
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [ord].[LineItems]
  WHERE [Notes] = o.[Notes] AND [OrderId] <> o.[OrderId]
)
```